# Show that $\{x\}$ is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\{x\},$ the number $\varepsilon=|y-x|$ is positive. If $z \in(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon),$ then $|z-y|<\varepsilon$ hence
$$
\varepsilon=|x-y|=|x-z+z-y| \leq|x-z|+|z-y|
$$
so that $|z-x| \geq \varepsilon-|z-y|>0$ and then  $z \neq x,$ so $z \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\{x\} .$ This proves that  $(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon) \subset \mathbb{R} \backslash\{x\}.$

This is my question: Why if $z \in\mathbb{R}-\{x\}$ implies $(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon) \subset \mathbb{R} \backslash\{x\}$ i dont understand that step

Comment: There is no such step. The argument is that if $y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$, and $\epsilon=|y-x|$, then $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: To show that $(y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$, it suffices to show that $z \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$ for every $z \in (y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

A set $Z$ is *open* if for each $y\in Z$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B(y;\epsilon)\subset Z$

In $\Bbb R, B(y;\epsilon)=(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$

Here, $Z=\Bbb R\setminus \{x\}$, and we take $\epsilon=|y-x|>0$, giving us that $y+\epsilon=x$ *or* $y-\epsilon=x$

Since the open ball *does not* contain it's end points, we have that $x\not\in B(y;\epsilon)\subset \Bbb R\implies B(y;\epsilon)\subset \Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$

And so the set is open, and it's complement, $\{x\}$, is closed